# Rank of abelian p-group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian p-group such that
$$
G=A_1\times \cdots A_n
$$
is the direct product of $n$ cyclic groups
then rank$(G)=n$.

The minimal number of generator of a group is the rank of G.

This theorem comes form the book *The theory of Finite Group an introduction*  (Hans Kurzwil) page 48, the author does not explain anything about it, only state it, maybe it is very obvious for the author, but I do not know why.

Comment: The group $G$ has a set of generators consisting of $n$ elements; can it be generated by fewer elements?

Comment: @egreg Yes it is what I want to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a surjective morphism from 
$$G= \mathbb{Z}/p^{e_1} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p^{e_n}$$

to 
$$\mathbb{Z}/p \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p$$
a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/p$ of dimension $n$. If $G$ was generated by less than $n$ elements then so would be $\mathbb{Z}/p \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p$, not possible.

Indeed, assume that  $\mathbb{Z}/p \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p$ is generated by $m$ elements $x_1, \ldots x_m$. Note that every element in $\mathbb{Z}/p \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p$ satisfies $p x=0$. Therefore, every element in $\mathbb{Z}/p \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p$ can be written as 
$$x = a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_m x_m$$
where $0 \le a_i \le p-1$. We can obtain in this way at most $p^m$ elements. Therefore $p^m \ge p^n$ and so $m\ge n$.

Comment: this book is only about group theory,author does not talk about linear algebra, so can you only use group theory to explain it? thanks.

Comment: @noname1014: Good point, I added an counting argument that works for $\mathbb{Z}/p$, a finite field.